# How to make 2 (frame?) using twitter bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]this is what I started to make in twitter bootstrap..
I am new using this.. Can you help me to make a 2 split page inside the html
that the menu in header when scrolled down will not disappear ..
I made html codes below Thanks!!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Teacher</title>
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <style type="text/css">`
            /* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */
            body{
            margin-top: 1px;
            }
            .divide-nav{
            height: 80px;
            background-color: #428bca;
            }
            .divide-text{
            color:#fff;
            line-height: 20px;
            font-size:20px;
            padding: 15px 0;
            }
            .affix {
            top: 1px;
            width:100%;
            }
            .filler{
            min-height: 2000px;
            }
            .navbar-form {
            padding-left: 0;
            }
            .navbar-collapse{
            padding-left:0; 
            }
            #footer {
            height: 60px;
            background-color: #f5f5f5;
            }
        </style>
        <style type="text/css"></style>
    </head>
    <!-- HTML code from Bootply.com editor -->
    <body>
        <div class="divide-nav">
            <div class="container">
                <p class="divide-text"><img src ="musar-logo.png"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-lower affix-top" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse collapse-buttons">
                    <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
                        <button class="btn btn-success">Button</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-default">Button</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-default">Button</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-default">Button</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <frameset cols="25%,*,25%">
            <frame src="1.html">
            <frame src="it.html">
            <frame src="it.html">
        </frameset>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="filler"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <!-- Your first column here -->
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <!-- Your second column here -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <!-- JavaScript jQuery code from Bootply.com editor  -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {

                $('.navbar-lower').affix({
            offset: {top: 50}
            });

            });

        </script>
        <div id="footer">
            <div class="container">
                <p class="text-muted credit">Footer Trial</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on the above answer, I put up a fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/w7s2o90e/1/

```
        <title>Teacher</title>
    <!-- HTML code from Bootply.com editor -->
    <body>
        <div class="divide-nav">
            <div class="container">
                <p class="divide-text"><img src ="musar-logo.png"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-lower affix-top" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse collapse-buttons">
                    <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
                        <button class="btn btn-success">Button</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-default">Button</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-default">Button</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-default">Button</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <frameset cols="25%,*,25%">
            <frame src="1.html">
            <frame src="it.html">
            <frame src="it.html">
        </frameset>
 <div class="row-fluid">
   <div id="left" class="col-sm-4">
     <div id="allYourContent" class= "col-sm-12">
    </div>
     </div>
  <div id="right" class="col-sm-8">
    <!--Body content-->
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
        <div id="footer">
            <div class="container">
                <p class="text-muted credit">Footer Trial</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

If you want a fixed size and the left side to scroll use

```
overflow:scroll
```

in your css.

The two columns from above work, but until you add content or a size to them, they won't show up (see fiddle). I used

```
class="col-sm-4" & class="col-sm-8"
```

instead of "span" but it should be similar.

I didn't edit all of your code, but it looks generally like what you were trying to achieve.

Comment: when I change the #right{ and #left{ into
 height:800px; the fix button header at the top is not fix already.. It doesn't follow until the class="col-sm-4" & class="col-sm8" ended..

Comment: class="col-sm8" was a typo, try class="col-sm-8"
Also, I'm not quite sure what you are saying. Can you clarify? The bootstrap layout you are using collapses the nav bar under a certain size. Try changing the size of your browser. If you want to change the size at which things change, try changing the "sm" key in the classes to "xs", "md" or  "lg" that changes the break point for your media queries (screen size changes)

Answer (score 0):

You can make a two grid layout to achieve this.
You can find more documentation on this at 
http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html

```
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row-fluid">
   <div class="span2">
     <!--Sidebar content-->
    </div>
  <div class="span10">
    <!--Body content-->
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```